# How to open a text file that contains numbers, and print the sum. Must use a for/while loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, sum

Title says all, I want to have a script that opens a text file, finds the numbers, (in number form not like "one" "two" etc) and prints/returns the sum of those numbers.

This is all I have:

```
def count_num(filename):
    myfile=open(filename)
    text=myfile.read
    words=text.split()
    for word in words:
```

Comment: Elaborate "finds the numbers" please? Are the numbers gonna be one every line, on the same line, interspersed between text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple approach

```
def count_num(filename):
    myfile = open(filename)
    text = myfile.read() # Note: added parentheses
    words = text.split()
    sum_ = 0
    for word in words:
        # Check if can convert to int type safely
        sum_ += int(word) if word.isdigit() else 0

    return sum_

print(count_num(some_file))
```

or slightly better one:

```
def count_num(filename):
    text = open(filename).read()
    numbers = map(int, filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), text.split()))
    return sum(numbers)

print(count_num(some_file))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much this worked well. I'm just wondering if I can ask if my interpretation of what you have written is correct? Also sorry for the bad format which you edited. Anyway, So 1. You named it sum_ because you can't name it sum as that is a function? 2. for the actual process, is it going through the text, and upon finding a word that "isdigit" returns as true, it adds the number to the variable sum?

Comment: @user3528330 1. yes, and I've added the additional way to do it (with `sum` function); 2. yes

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_num(filename):
    nums = open(filename).read().split()
    sums = 0
    for k in nums:
        sums+=(int(k))
    return sums
```

In a file named `nums.txt` with the following data:

```
1 3 5 3 2 5 3 4 2 42 12 43
```

The code runs as the following

```
>>> count_num('nums.txt')
125
```

Comment: Hi there, i'm fairly new and am wondering what this k variable means? Correct me if i'm wrong but it isn't defined anywhere in the code?

Comment: In fact, `k` is defined in the `for` loop. `Nums` is a list, and I am looping over every value of it and assigning that new value to `k` every time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file has only numbers and no text, your solution is as simple as doing:

```
def count_num(filename):
    myfile=open(filename)
    text=myfile.read()
    words=text.split()
    n_data = [int(a) for a in words if a.isdigit()]
    return sum(n_data)
```

[`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#sum) is a built-in type in python that returns the sum of a iterable.

We do `n_data = [int(a) for a in words if a.isdigit()]` to convert all of the digits in the string format to `int`.